# How to make all cells in heatmap square

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, heatmap

Hey I'm plotting a heatmap of a pandas dataframe but the cells on the top and bottom rows are not square / the same shape or size as the rest, see image.
What am I missing?

```
sns.heatmap(mat, ax=ax, cmap=cmap, linewidths=.5, square=True)
```

[image]
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating matplotlib fixed this issue. Apparently it was an issue with matplotlib 3.1.1 see https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1773